# Sort a dataframe in which one column contains nan values

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe.

```
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Item Type  | Year_Month | Total Cost | Diff |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Baby Food  | Jul-2017   | 3000       | 100  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Baby Food  | Jun-2017   | 2900       | 100  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Cereal     | Jul-2017   | 6000       | 1000 |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Cereal     | Jun-2017   | 5000       | 1000 |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Snacks     | Jul-2017   | 4500       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Chocolates | Jul-2017   | 3000       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Ice Cream  | Jul-2017   | 4000       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
```

I want to sort the dataframe based on diff but when it contains Nan in that case it should sort according to Total Cost. So my final output will look like

```
+------------+------------+------------+------+
|  Item Type | Year_Month | Total Cost | Diff |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Cereal     | Jul-2017   | 6000       | 1000 |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Cereal     | Jun-2017   | 5000       | 1000 |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Baby Food  | Jul-2017   | 3000       | 100  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Baby Food  | Jun-2017   | 2900       | 100  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Snacks     | Jul-2017   | 4500       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Ice Cream  | Jul-2017   | 4000       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Chocolates | Jul-2017   | 3000       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
```

One way of doing it is break the dataframe into 2 dataframe(One containing all the rows with diff is not equal to Nan and other dataframe with rows when diff is equal to Nan). And then sort each of the dataframe based on Diff and Total Cost and then combine them.

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------+
| Item Type | Year_Month | Total Cost | Diff |
+-----------+------------+------------+------+
| Baby Food | Jul-2017   | 3000       | 100  |
+-----------+------------+------------+------+
| Baby Food | Jun-2017   | 2900       | 100  |
+-----------+------------+------------+------+
| Cereal    | Jul-2017   | 6000       | 1000 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------+
| Cereal    | Jun-2017   | 5000       | 1000 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------+


+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Item Type  | Year_Month | Total Cost | Diff |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Snacks     | Jul-2017   | 4500       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Ice Cream  | Jul-2017   | 4000       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
| Chocolates | Jul-2017   | 3000       | Nan  |
+------------+------------+------------+------+
```

Is there any other optimized way of doing this, as this will involve a lot of computation?

Answer (score 1):

When sorting a dataframe(df) by a column('Diff' here), the Nan Values goes to the end of the dataframe. So by sorting the dataframe by 2 columns( 'Diff' and 'Total Cost'), we can arrive at required results.

Here is the code for the same:

```
    df=df.sort_values(by=['Diff','Total Cost'],ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sort function with a key of function:

**In:**

```
import json

jsonv = [
 {
   "Item Type": "Snacks",
   "Year_Month": "Jul-2017",
   "Total Cost": 4500,
   "Diff": "5"
 },
 {
   "Item Type": "Ice Cream",
   "Year_Month": "Jul-2017",
   "Total Cost": 4000,
   "Diff": "Nan"
 },
 {
   "Item Type": "Chocolates",
   "Year_Month": "Jul-2017",
   "Total Cost": 3000,
   "Diff": "4"
 }
]

def extract_diff(json):
    try:
        jdiff = json['Diff']
        ret = int(jdiff) if jdiff != 'Nan' else 0
        return ret
    except KeyError:
        return 0

jsonv.sort(key=extract_diff, reverse=True)

print(json.dumps(jsonv, indent=4))
```

**Out:**

```
[
    {
        "Item Type": "Snacks",
        "Year_Month": "Jul-2017",
        "Total Cost": 4500,
        "Diff": "5"
    },
    {
        "Item Type": "Chocolates",
        "Year_Month": "Jul-2017",
        "Total Cost": 3000,
        "Diff": "4"
    },
    {
        "Item Type": "Ice Cream",
        "Year_Month": "Jul-2017",
        "Total Cost": 4000,
        "Diff": "Nan"
    }
]
```